# cloud9-ide don't show leaflet maps

Tags: maps, leaflet, cloud9-ide

I work in aproject using HTML5, all is ok on my desktop but when I deploy on C9 using Leaflet don't show the maps.

The rest of the webpage is ok, only the map's don't show

Comment: Have you checked the browser's developer console? If there are errors there, they could tell you what the problem is. Paste a screenshot in your question if you need help after that.

Comment: don't send errors the console, the external connection to leaflet is the problem                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/own_style.css">                       <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

Comment: If there were any problems loading these files, there should've been an error in the browser console. Also, can you try prefixing `//` to the urls? so, `"//cdnjs..."` and there shouldn't be a `;` after the url

Comment: doesn`t work, I work with http://code.jquery....., http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js. same results. When I be in bluehost all was ok

Comment: The url is https://laguna-ujat.c9users.io/index50.html

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the link provided in the link above. The library you're trying to access is hardcoded via HTTP while the site is being served via HTTPS. Since Cloud9 supports both HTTP and HTTPS, you can use https://laguna-ujat.c9users.io/index50.html or http://laguna-ujat.c9users.io/index50.html. If you access the site using HTTP://... you'll see that the map loads. Accessing HTTP resources within an HTTPS site isn't allowed by browsers and they block the resource loading.

The way to import urls from CDN without running into this issue is via protocol-less urls. So the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
```

becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
```

I hope this helps.